# Can not get my if statement to trigger using pytz timing for an alarm system

Tags: python, loops, pytz

Using pytz to get a time. When the time is equal to a variable (string time), I want text to be printed (eventually a sound to be played). The time is iterating, but I can not get the statement to print when there is a match.

```
    #imports
import time

from datetime import datetime

import pytz

#current time
def clocktime():

    while True:
        tz_syd = pytz.timezone("Australia/Sydney")
        Sydney_Time = datetime.now(tz_syd).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        time.sleep(1)

#iterator to check for time match
def alarmsystem(clocktime):
    TestCaseA = "20:52:16"
    TestCaseB = "20:53:29"

    while True:
        if clocktime == TestCaseB:
            print("Time B Triggered")
        elif clocktime == TestCaseA:
            print("Time A Triggered")

print(alarmsystem(clocktime()))
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function clocktime() never stops running. Nor does it return or share anything about the time with alarmsystem().

When you write alarmsystem(clocktime()), the code will run and do clocktime() first. When ever clocktime() is done (never) it will send the return value (None in you case) to the function alarmsystem().

I assume what you want is that clocktime() runs continuously in the background, and the function alarmsystem() will trigger when that timer hits a certain time.

For this you need to have clocktime() run in a different thread.

If all your program needs to do is trigger on a certain time you can use the following code:

```
def alarmsystem():
    TestCaseA = "20:52:16"
    TestCaseB = "20:53:29"

    while True:
        tz_syd    = pytz.timezone("Australia/Sydney")
        clocktime = datetime.now(tz_syd).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        if clocktime == TestCaseB:
            print("Time B Triggered")
        elif clocktime == TestCaseA:
            print("Time A Triggered")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it has absolutely helped! Would there be a case where this could work with the clocktime as one function, and the alarm system as another?